# On per-thread basis, the OS does not maintain virtual memory state?

Tags: multithreading, process, operating-system

A thread is usually defined as a *lightweight process* because the OS maintains smaller data structures for a thread than for a process.

I have two questions:

1. On per-thread basis, the OS does not maintain virtual memory state ?
2. On per-thread basis, the OS maintains only scheduling and accounting information ?

My reason: since per thread only stack and register are different , so (1) is true and (2) is false .

Is it correct ?

---

**Edit:** This is the original question

> A thread is usually defined as a "light weight process" because an
>   operating system (OS) maintains smaller data structures for a thread
>   than for a process. In relation to this, which of the following is
>   TRUE?
>
> (A) On per-thread basis, the OS maintains only CPU register state
>
> (B) The OS does not maintain separate stack for each thread
>
> (C) On per-thread basis, the OS does not maintain virtual memory state
>
> (D) On per-thread basis, the OS maintains only scheduling and
>   accounting information

Comment: What do you mean by virtual memory 'state'? Define exactly, 'cause the answer might be different. And the same definiton question for 'accounting'. What do you mean by that?

Comment: @SergeyA sir , I edited question.

Comment: 'A thread is usually defined as a "light weight process' - not really.  A thread is the OS unit of execution.  SInce a process must contain at least one thread, (else it could not do anything), it's more correct to suggest that a process is a heavyweight collection of threads.

Comment: B is true, each thread has its own stack

Answer (score 4):

A thread shares its virtual memory with the process it belongs to. This makes all the constructs we commonly see in multi-threading possible, where we simply exchange data between threads by writing to variables.

This also means that threads are quicker to start, since the OS does not need to load/setup the binary image, run initialization code etc. like it does for separate processes (created with e.g. `fork(2)`).

However, threads are independent units to the operating systems CPU scheduler and thus the OS does keep indeed separate scheduling information for each thread.